# What's this connection in my garage?

Tags: plumbing, uk, connectors

Can someone tell me what kind of connection this is for?

[image]

Comment: what comes out when you open that tap?

Answer (score 1):

That is the drain point for either the heating system ie radiators as it is the lowest point or it could be the drain for the boiler.

What is on the other side of the wall - that may help, but I would go with the drain for the radiators.

Answer (score -2):

That is a "drain cock", they are installed at the lowest point on a pipe system and allow a hose to be connected to drain down the system  without making too much of a mess.

What exactly it is draining cannot be distinguished by looking at it. Might be the cold water system, might be the hot water system, might be the central heating system.